# Unable to retrieve parameter from kprobe | eBPF

Tags: ebpf

Trying to install a hook on renameat2 to detect file renames.

It seems the hooks executes on each rename, however I am unable to get/parse the parameters.

Below is my code:

```
SEC("kprobe/__x64_sys_renameat2")
int kprobe_renameat2(struct pt_regs *ctx)
{
    struct data_t data = {}; 

    u64 uid = bpf_get_current_uid_gid() & 0xFFFFFFFF;

    data.pid = bpf_get_current_pid_tgid();
    data.uid = uid;
    data.op_code = 4;

    int ret = bpf_probe_read_user_str(&data.newpath, sizeof(data.newpath), (const char *)PT_REGS_PARM2(ctx));
    data.debug = ret;

    bpf_perf_event_output(ctx, &output, BPF_F_CURRENT_CPU,  &data, sizeof(data));

    return 0;
}
```

It seems ret is always 0;
I also tried to retriever other parameters, the dont make sense.

What I am missing?

Below is prototype of renameat2:

```
int renameat2(int olddirfd, const char *oldpath,
                    int newdirfd, const char *newpath, unsigned int flags);
```